# The website doesn't show information in chromedriver/geckodriver (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to scrap https://wizzair.com/en-gb/flights/timetable#/.
It went well for some time. But since today, I can't achieve flight information, as the Wizz server doesn't return anything, with the "An error has occurred. Please try again. If the error persists, please contact the airline." error.

[image: screen here]

I have tried to access the website not from Selenium but from .exe manually, the same thing, for both geckodriver and chrome's one.
So, it seems that the website knows that it's a tool for automatic management and doesn't return any information.

Do you have any advice how to fix it?

Thanks,

UPDATE:
Saved WebPage, accessed with and without WebDriver, can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OsqfKqKyqpOLBMdUbunYH7GUQZgqtRXJ?usp=sharing

Code trial

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ".\\resources\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/dev/null");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(2000, 0)); // move window to the second display
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://wizzair.com/en-gb/flights/timetable/clujnapoca/vienna--#/1/0/1/0/0/2019-01/2019-01");
```

Comment: Your code trials, relevant HTML and error stack trace please.

Comment: @DebanjanB, Updated. 
Sorry for the delay, for some time, the error disappeared, and now it came back.

There's no any StackTrace, as the error is shown on WebSide, and the issue is that it returns no flights, when there are some.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the headers in the HTTP request, and or change some of the system properties to hide the fact that you're using the selenium browser.

**To set system properties:**

```
System.setProperty(property, value);
```

**To see which properties your JVM supports, open up a console (CMD/terminal) and type:**

`java -XshowSettings:all`

**Setting system properties example:**

```
static {
    System.setProperty("user.dir", "C:\\Users\\YourName");
}
```

***System properties reference:*** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

---

**Masking your connection to a website:**

***Note:*** `URLConnection#addRequestProperty` are how you set the headers to send to a website. You can use `HTTP`, or `HTTPS`, they're in the same, or very close to, general package of `URLConnection`.

```
private static final String LINUX_USER_AGENT =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62" + ".0";
private static final String WINDOWS_USER_AGENT =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) " + "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0";

/**
 * Masks the URL connection as a regular one would be 403 forbidden
 *
 * @param url
 *      - URL to mask and connect to
 * @return the masked url connection to the website
 *
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static InputStreamReader getMaskedInputStream(String url) throws IOException
{
    URL website = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win"))
    {
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", WINDOWS_USER_AGENT);
    }
    else
    {
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", LINUX_USER_AGENT);
    }
    connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    return new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
}

/**
 * Masks the URL connection as a regular one would be 403 forbidden
 *
 * @param url
 *      - URL to mask and connect to
 * @return the masked url connection to the website
 *
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static InputStreamReader getMaskedInputStream(Proxy proxy, Authenticator auth, String url) throws IOException
{
    Authenticator.setDefault(auth);
    final URL website = new URL(url);
    final URLConnection connection = website.openConnection(proxy);
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win"))
    {
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", WINDOWS_USER_AGENT);
    }
    else
    {
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", LINUX_USER_AGENT);
    }
    connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    return new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
}
```

Comment: Could you please advise how exactly getMaskedInputStream can be used in the .setProperty?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but where can InputStreamReader be used?
As webDriver.get() receives as parameter only String. 
Or should it be used for some system property you have been talking in the first part of the message?